# Programmatically configure application pools to support smooth streaming publishing points?

Tags: c#, iis, cmd, smooth-streaming, windows-media-services

I am looking for information as how to tackle Programmatically configuring application pools to support smooth streaming publishing points.

Reference to this Smooth Streaming IIS guide [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/live-smooth-streaming/creating-and-managing-live-smooth-streaming-publishing-points) to configure via the interface. But i need to take any complication away from the end user.

So i need to configure via cmd/ script or c#.

The alert on the interface is as pictured below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok just in case anybody wants to get past this Application pool alert.
here is the snapshot of the Application pool settings in this instance the default pool.
The Alert

[image]

[image: Defualt application pool settings]

After the application Pool settings were updated

[image]

**Command prompt solution**

To enable the Action via CommandPrompt do as follows 
Replacing **DefaultAppPool** with whatever name the Application pool is called

Run Command Prompt as administrator

```
Cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='DefaultAppPool'].processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00

appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00

appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation:true

appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /recycling.disallowRotationOnConfigChange:true
```